# pylab plot showing asymptotes

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

How can I remove the asymptote?

```
import numpy as np

e = 1.26
beta = .705 * np.pi
rph = 7000
re = 6378

def r(nuh):
    return rph * (1 + e) / (1 + e * np.cos(nuh + beta))


theta = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, 50000)

fig2 = pylab.figure()
ax2 = fig2.add_subplot(111)
ax2.plot(r(theta) * np.cos(theta), r(theta) * np.sin(theta))
ax2.plot(rph * np.cos(theta), rph * np.sin(theta), 'r')
#  adding the Earth                                                                 
earth2 = pylab.Circle((0, 0), radius = re, color = 'b')
ax2.add_patch(earth2)
pylab.xlim((-50000, 100000))
pylab.ylim((-50000, 100000))
pylab.show()
```

[image: with asymptotes]

Comment: What's the asymptote? Also, you haven't defined `re`.

Comment: @askewchan The asymptotes are the superfluous straight lines drawing when plotting the hyperbola.  re is defined now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10377593/1730674), setting the divergent points to `np.nan` will cause them not to be plotted.

In your problem, it is `r(theta)` which diverges.  Define `r` and `theta` in the usual way, but then, you want to set the extrema of `r(theta)` to `np.nan`.

To do this, make an array first, then change its extrema to `np.nan`:

```
rt = r(theta)
ext = [np.argmin(rt), np.argmax(rt)]
rt[ext] = np.nan
```

Now, be sure to plot with the modified `rt` array not the original function:

```
ax2.plot(rt * np.cos(theta), rt * np.sin(theta))
```

[image: No asymptotes :)]