# X axis for plt.plot not consistent with data for x axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, x-axis

Below is a snippet of the code I am using to analyze the volume of ES (s&p futures).

```
esVolume = (es['Volume']).loc['2023-03-15 09:00:00-04:00':'2023-03-15 10:29:00-04:00']
```

plt.plot(Time.minute(900,1030), esVolume)

Why does the x-axis include increments 960-999 when the domain of the graph is `[900,959] U [1000,1030]` ?

[image: plot]

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10377593/how-to-drop-connecting-lines-where-the-function-is-discontinuous

Answer (score 0):

Matplotlib tries to create a continuous range of x and the plot. To override this behavior you need to manually define the `xticks` for matplotlib

```
arr = [100*(i//60) + i%60 + 900 for i in range(0,10000)]
plt.plot(arr,arr,'ro')
plt.xticks(arr[::5])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: My data increments are 1 min intervals so I want 1000 to follow 959 (no break in the graph).